# How to debug Axios Errors in Google Cloud Functions?

Tags: firebase, axios, google-cloud-functions, google-sheets-api

These beauties come up from cloud functions. Not reproducible or traceable to a particular part of my code, and intermittent. My code updates a Google Sheets Spreadsheet whenever Firestore documents change. It uses Axios version 0.19.0

```
      {
        "textPayload": "Error: Internal error encountered.
at createError (/srv/node_modules/google-auth-library/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)
    at settle (/srv/node_modules/google-auth-library/node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:18:12
    at Unzip.handleStreamEnd (/srv/node_modules/google-auth-library/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:202:11)
    at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
    at Unzip.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:139:11)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:219:9)",
        "insertId": "000000-a360be33-0241-4c2a-befa-3b66f8c69cec",
        "resource": {
          "type": "cloud_function",
          "labels": {
            "function_name": "prodAppendReport",
            "project_id": "proj-inv23",
            "region": "us-central1"
          }
        },
        "timestamp": "2019-11-27T17:04:40.480Z",
        "severity": "ERROR",
        "labels": {
          "execution_id": "860406302152954"
        },
        "logName": "projects/proj-inv23/logs/cloudfunctions.googleapis.com%2Fcloud-functions",
        "trace": "projects/proj-inv23/traces/53a5ce20f7f3f77329f1bae22425317e",
        "receiveTimestamp": "2019-11-27T17:04:42.029780023Z"
      }
```

And this one

```
{
    "textPayload": "Error
at Http2CallStream.call.on (/srv/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:96:45)
at emitOne (events.js:121:20)
at Http2CallStream.emit (events.js:211:7)
at process.nextTick (/srv/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:71:22)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:132:7)
at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:219:9)",
    "insertId": "000001-cccf1181-a0a5-49bf-a4ec-d889632a418f",
    "resource": {
      "type": "cloud_function",
      "labels": {
        "function_name": "testAppendReport",
        "project_id": "proj-inv23",
        "region": "us-central1"
      }
    },
    "timestamp": "2019-11-26T04:19:51.014Z",
    "severity": "ERROR",
    "labels": {
      "execution_id": "858243858307172"
    },
    "logName": "projects/proj-inv23/logs/cloudfunctions.googleapis.com%2Fcloud-functions",
    "trace": "projects/proj-inv23/traces/3edb963f0baefed82208a26711f04c46",
    "receiveTimestamp": "2019-11-26T04:19:52.566346377Z"
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discovered that we were using a super old version of google-auth-library which depends on an old version of Axios (0.18.0). We switched to the latest version which doesn't even use Axios anymore, so far so good.